# How to find the angle Theta from the Figure?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, angle

I have the following figure and want to find angle $\theta$ from the figure
[image: Find angle theta]

I know the slope of the two lines can be obtained from :
\begin{align}
m1 = \frac{Y2 - Y1} {X2 - X1}
\end{align}
Similarly,
\begin{align}
m2 = \frac{Y4 - Y3}{X4 - X3}
\end{align}

Now i know that to find an angle between the given two lines is:
\begin{align}
\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac{m2 - m1}{1 + m1*m2})  
\end{align}
But i am not sure that the $\theta$ obtained is certainly the $\theta$ from my drawing.

Please help me out how I can resolve this.

Comment: I think it will give $\pi - \theta$ the way you have defined $m_1$. I would recommend using vectors instead $a \cdot b = |a| |b| \cos \theta$ going from $P_1$ to $P_2$ and from $P_1$ to $P_3$. It is then easy to see which angle you get. Subtract from $\pi$ to get $\theta$.

Comment: @MathLover I am not able to get you. Please can you help me with the m=notations I have used so it will be simple for me to understand.

Comment: Basically I am calling $(X_1, Y_1)$ as $P_1$ and so on. The way you have defined $m_1$ and $m_2$, it should give you $\pi - \theta$ but my point is instead just use vectors and it is less confusing on which angle you are finding.

Comment: OK so I just worked it and what you have gives you $\theta$, and not $(\pi-\theta)$ (what I mentioned earlier was incorrect). So you are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From dot product between 2 vectors:

$$a \cdot b = |a||b|cos\theta \\
cos\theta = \frac{a \cdot b}{|a||b|}
$$

Building vectors from coordinates:

$$a = (X1-X2, Y1-Y2) \\
b = (X3-X4, Y3-Y4)
$$

To sum up it all together:

$$cos\theta = \frac{(X1 - X2)(X3-X4) + (Y1-Y2)(Y3-Y4)}{\sqrt{(X1-X2)^2 + (Y1-Y2)^2}\sqrt{(X3-X4)^2 + (Y3-Y4)^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Draw a horizontal line that intersects the vertex of $\theta,$ and let $\theta=\theta_1+\theta_2$ such that
$\theta_1$ is below $\theta_2$ and both together are vertically opposite $\theta.$

By definition of gradient, $$\theta_1=-\arctan(m_1)$$
and $$\theta_2=\arctan(m_2).$$

Thus, $$\theta=\arctan(-m_1)+\arctan(m_2).$$

Since $\theta$ is acute, the arctangent addition formula applies: $$\theta=\arctan\frac{(-m_1)+(m_2)}{1-(-m_1)(m_2)}\\
=\arctan\frac{m_2-m_1}{1+m_1m_2}.$$